# Monitors wake up immediately after lock

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, monitor, lock-screen, wakeup

I changed my pc recently and reinstalled Ubuntu from scratch (20.04 LTS). Now when I lock the pc or when it locks automatically after 5 minutes (default setting), the monitors will turn themselves back on almost immediately after turning off. It varies, but they will either show the lock screen forever or go to a black (but turned on) screen.

Aside from the tower, everything else (monitors, all peripherals) are the same I used to have in my previous pc, which didn't have this issue.

(EDIT: There's actually **one** difference. One of the monitors used to be plugged into a VGA port. I'm now using a DisplayPort to VGA adapter for that one. Could that be causing the wake-up?)

This does **not** wake the pc up from suspend, however. When suspended, both the tower and monitors will turn off as they should, and no issues. This is only when locked.

Tried unplugging every USB peripheral one at a time, see which was turning them back on, but to no avail, even when left only with keyboard **or** mouse, they'd still do the same.

Any ideas on what it might be/how to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently and probably you have similar case. In my case this was caused by monitor internal setting named **Input Control -> Auto-Switch Input** (or similar for other monitor model). I just turned off auto-switch option for my HP Z24i G2 and set detection mode to HDMI only.